# Сравнение двух списков, нахождения во втором списке новых элементов

Tags: python, синтаксис

Есть два списка:

> lst1 = ['Белое', 'Красное' , 'Синие' , 'Зеленое']
>
> lst2 = ['Белое ', 'Красное' , 'Синие' , 'Зеленое', 'Черное', 'Серое']

Мне надо

1. При сравнении если во втором списке есть элементы, которых нет в первом  - флаг True, если при сравнении во втором списке нет  элементов, которых нетв первом списке - флаг False

2.Сравнить два списка и новые элементы из второго списка записать в новый список.

Результат

> Флаг True
>
> lst3 = ['Черное', 'Серое']

Если бы сравнивались два таких списка

> lst1 = ['Белое', 'Красное' , 'Синие' , 'Зеленое']
>
> lst2 = ['Белое ', 'Красное' , 'Синие' ]

Результат

> Флаг False

Comment: Повторы могут быть в списках у вас?

Comment: Да. Если имеется ввиду что повторы - это если в обеих списках  одинаковые  элементы

Comment: Я имел ввиду `['Белое', 'Красное' , 'Зеленое' , 'Зеленое']` `lst2 = ['Белое', 'Красное' , 'Синие' , 'Зеленое', 'Зеленое', 'Зеленое']` Или же все элементы различны внутри одного списка?

Comment: все элементы различные

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
lst1 = ['Белое', 'Красное', 'Синие', 'Зеленое']
lst2 = ['Белое', 'Красное', 'Синие', 'Зеленое', 'Черное', 'Серое']

difference = list(set(lst2) - set(lst1))
flag = bool(difference)

print(difference)
print(flag)
```

```
lst1 = ['Белое', 'Красное', 'Синие', 'Зеленое']
lst2 = ['Белое', 'Красное', 'Синие', 'Зеленое', 'Черное', 'Серое']

set_from_first = set(lst1)
difference_2 = [x for x in lst2 if x not in set_from_first]

flag = bool(difference_2)

print(difference_2)
print(flag)
```

Comment: Нужно подправить код. Что бы новый список  с новыми элементами шел по тому же порядку как встречается в списке который сравнивается. Этот код выводит новые элементы но наоборот. Выводится первый элемент, который в списке для сравнения стоит последним. # сравнение списков
lst1 = ['Белое', 'Красное', 'Зеленое', 'Синие']
lst2 = ['желтое' ,'Красное', 'Синие',  'Серое']

difference = list(set(lst2) - set(lst1))
flag = bool(difference)

print(difference)
print(flag)